# How to convert list data to xml using python

Tags: python, xml, list

I have been trying to convert list data to xml file.

But getting below error : `ValueError: Invalid tag name '0'`

**This is my header** : `'Name,Job Description,Course'`

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [ 'Name,Job Description,Course' , 
   'Bob,Backend Developer,MCA',  
   'Raj,Business Analyst,BMS', 
   'Alice,FullStack Developer,CS' ]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
with open('output.xml', 'w') as myfile: 
  myfile.write(df.to_xml())
```

Comment: The format of your data isn't proper. Your `df` has `lst` indices as keys and `to_xml` is trying to create XML using key value(s) pairs. Hence it tried taking `0` as tag name for the first entry.

Comment: You can refer the examples here and update your issue https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html

Comment: @kiric8494 your dataframe doesn't have columns names, which will be used to make the tag names; so declare columns, e.g. like : df = pd.DataFrame(data=lst,columns=header_data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The df you created is improper. There are two scenarios.

1. If you took `name, job description, course` as single header. You
   will fail at the point of saving df to xml.
2. In order to save df as xml there is a format that need to be followed.

Below solution works. Hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [ ['Name','Job_Description','Course'] , 
['Bob','Backend Developer','MCA'],  
['Raj','Business Analyst','BMS'], 
['Alice','FullStack Developer','CS'] ]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst[1:], columns=[lst[0]])
print(df)
df.to_xml('./output.xml')
```

Comment: : Can you elaborate more on step : `pd.DataFrame(lst[1:], columns=[lst[0]])`

Comment: From your query I understood that `Name, job description, Course` are headers. So while creating the DataFrame I have mentioned these values as column names using variable `columns`. The remaining data in lst i.e. lst[1:] is appended under the respective columns. For better understanding of creating DataFrame refer : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html